# connection to sql from config variables cause error (php code)

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using variables from config file to establish sql connection on my php files. Connection works fine in those files but to make the website more organized I decided to have one file for connection. I got the code from the internet, the connection does not worked. 
giving me this error:

' Error: Connect failed: Access denied for user 'something'@'server.com' (using password: NO)'

The user info at the config file is different and the password is set.

This is the details:
My website like this structure:

```
root ----> 1)config.ini 2)public_html folder
public_html ----> website pages including 1)db_functions.php and 2)admin folder
admin ---->login.php and loginCode.php.
```

in the config.ini

```
[database]
username = someone
password = something
dbname = something
```

in db_functions.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Database functions for a MySQL with PHP tutorial
 * 
 * @copyright Eran Galperin
 * @license MIT License
 * @see http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17
 */

/**
 * Connect to the database
 * 
 * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
 */
function db_connect() {


    // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $connection;

    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($connection)) {
        // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
        $config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); 
        $connection = mysqli_connect('server',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $connection;
}
?>
```

in loginCode.php

```
<?php

require_once('../db_functions.php');
$connection = db_connect();
      //if connection fails, stop script execution
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            $Message = "Error: " . $sql  .  "Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error();
        echo $Message;
      }
      else
          echo 'no error';
?>
```

Those cods have error:
Error: Connect failed: Access denied for user 'something'@'server.com' (using password: NO)

However when I copied the same function from db_functions.php file to loginCode.php file and change this line `$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini');` to `$config = parse_ini_file('../../config.ini');` , it works perfectly and the connection  success.
Also it works without error when I replaced the connection variables in db_functions.php by the actual database user information, calling the function from loginCode.php.

I think there is a problem on db_functions.php who can not assess information in config file but why the other files can access it?

update: I moved loginCode.php file to public_html folder connection works. and I moved  db_functions.php file to admin folder it worked also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked when I put both files loginCode.php and db_functions.php in the same folder.